# Java JMenu opening. Open upwads instead of open down

Tags: java, swing, jmenu, jmenuitem, jmenupopup

Hi have the follow doubt: I want that my java JMenu can be opened upwards instead of opened down. At this moment I can't find any solution for it. I want your help.

I dont want this common behaviour, I want the opposite...

[image: JMenu opened down]
<sub>(source: [esimplesoft.es](http://www.esimplesoft.es/Tutorial/jmenu.png))</sub>

like that

[image: JMenu opened upwards]
<sub>(source: [bytescout.com](http://bytescout.com/files/images/examples/watermarking/paint_in_start_menu.png))</sub>

Comment: yes is possible to change location for `JPopup` for `JMenu` and/or `JComboBox`, for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: If you want it to open upwards, put the frame at the bottom of the screen.

Comment: The menu bar is at the top of the frame, so opening it upwards would, in most of the cases, make the menu invisible, because outside of the screen. Why would you want that? Moreover, 100% of menus open downwards. It's something that the users are expecting. Why would you want to annoy them?